# Distance between angle distributions

Tags: distributions, distance, uniform-distribution, kullback-leibler, circular-statistics

I want to quantify the complexity of the street network of different cities.

For each city I have the angle distribution of its streets.

[image: polar plot of Chicago's street network]

[image: polar plot of London's street network]

My hypothesis that the more complex the street network, the closer to the uniform distribution its street angle distribution. In the above plots, London's street network is much more complex than Chicago's.

To compute the distance to the uniform distribution I used the Kullback Leibler divergence and the Total Variation Distance but I get counter-intuitive results: London's KLD and TVD are higher than Chicago's, so I'm not sure these are valid for angle distributions...

Is there any specific distance I should use for this kind of data?

Thanks!

Edit #1: here is the code I used

```
import numpy as np
import osmnx as ox, pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

place='Chicago, USA'
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G), node_size=0)
# calculate edge bearings and visualize their frequency
G = ox.add_edge_bearings(G)
bearings = pd.Series([data['bearing'] for u, v, k, data in G.edges(keys=True, data=True)])
ax = bearings.hist(bins=30, zorder=2, alpha=0.8)
xlim = ax.set_xlim(0, 360)
ax.set_title(place + ' street network edge bearings')
plt.show()

def KL(a, b):
a = np.asarray(a, dtype=np.float)
b = np.asarray(b, dtype=np.float)

return np.sum(np.where(a != 0, a * np.log(a / b), 0))

def tvd(a, b):
a = np.asarray(a, dtype=np.float)
b = np.asarray(b, dtype=np.float)
return sum(abs(a-b))/2

#uniform distribution
unif_array=np.full((bearings.size), 1/float(bearings.size)) 
unif_array=unif_array/np.sum(unif_array)
#normalized angle distribution
bearing_norm=bearings/np.sum(bearings)

print KL(bearing_norm,unif_array)
print tvd(bearing_norm,unif_array)

# for Chicago, KL = 0.138 and TVD = 0.218
# for London, KL = 0.194 and TVD = 0.249
```

Edit #2:  I found my mistake, I defined the uniform distribution as `unif_array=np.full((bearings.size), 1/float(bearings.size))`
 when it should be 
`unif_array = np.random.uniform(0,360,bearings.size)`

Comment: You might have miscalculated.  Could you explain how you have tried to compute these distances, perhaps with a small example?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added the code I used to compute the KLD and TVD.
The angle distribution is in the array bearings, computed with the osmnx package (https://geoffboeing.com/2018/02/street-network-orientation/)

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, without providing a (minimal) reproducible example, it doesn't get us much further towards determining what is going wrong.  One thing does appear amiss: you don't seem to be looking at "directions," but only two-way *orientations.*  This causes you to halve all the estimated probabilities, which changes the distances.  These calculations also depend (strongly) on how you bin the data, so it's important to show that detail.

Comment: I added the rest of the code, but most of it is hidden in the osmnx functions.
I agree with you about the two-way orientation, I will try to "fold" the distributions and work only within [0,pi]. I only bin the data for the plot, bearings contains continuous values so I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: It's a huge issue: how are you computing the KL distance without binning?  Therein could be your problem.

Comment: Computing the KL distance doesn't require binning, if I'm correct (see [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9262/calculating-kl-divergence-in-python)). 

I found my mistake, I defined the uniform distribution as
`unif_array=np.full((bearings.size), 1/float(bearings.size)) `
when it should be
`unif_array = np.random.uniform(0,180,bearings.size)`.
I'm stupid. Thanks for your time !

Comment: I believe you misinterpret that post.  You can see the problem in your approach by varying how you represent your data: for instance, by changing the bin size you will dramatically change your computation of the KL distance.  The fundamental problem is that you need an estimate of the probability *density* and your calculation will be extremely sensitive to that.  If you like, you are free to ignore this issue, but the risk is that everything you do might be meaningless or nonsensical.

Comment: I'm not sure to follow you. The KL is sum(a*log(a / b)), with a and b two distributions. Here it is two ditribution of angles, I don't see where the binning intervene.

Comment: If you are referring to the *empirical* distributions of the data, then computing KL divergences is virtually worthless.  In particular, such distributions are so incompatible with continuous distributions (such as the uniform distribution) that their KL divergences are all infinite.  Your formula applies only to two *discrete* distributions *defined on the same set.*  That excludes applying it to the uniform distribution.  Typically, people use the data to *estimate* some underlying distribution (that's what the binning is for) and then use that to compute the KL divergence.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the empirical and the uniform distributions are incompatible? They both represent angles between 0 and 180°, normalized to sum to unity.

If I follow you, the only way to use KL is to estimate an underlying distribution through binning, which can severely bias the result. So KS doesn't really seem to be the way to go. What about kolmogorov-smirnoff statistic, could it be used directly with the empirical distributions of the data?

Comment: The uniform distribution has a density; the empirical distribution does not.  That automatically makes their KL divergence infinite.  And yes, severe bias is a problem--that's why this method is rarely used, except with large datasets.  I don't see how a KS statistic would be any meaningful way to quantify the "complexity" of the underlying street network, though.  This all begs the question of what you actually mean by "complexity" and how these summaries of directions might relate to that.  It sounds like these are considerations you need to address before going further.

Comment: Isn't the empirical distribution divided by the sum of its values a density? All its values are between 0 and 1 and they sum to unity. 
The KS statistic between a distribution D and the uniform distribution would quantify the distance between the two, a bit like the KLD. 
As I put in the original post, I define 'complexity' as the (inverse of the) distance of the street network angle distribution to the uniform distribution. A city with street angles in every direction is more 'complex' than a city with only perpendicular streets. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: No, an empirical distribution can never be a density.  One property of a density is that it assigns *zero* probability to any particular value.  Regardless, the KS distance captures so little information about how two distributions differ that it's scarcely worth considering in your application.